# What is a good book for learning mechanics at the JEE advanced level?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

JEE Advanced is an entrance exam for admissions to IITs in India. I will be giving the exam next year. The exam focuses mainly on problem solving skills. So I need recommendations for a book i can use to learn mechanics. If anyone knows about video lectures that could help me,feel free to share.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Book recommendations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/)

Comment: We made a separate chat room for JEE people [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54160/problem-solving-strategies), you can probably get some great answers from them!

Answer (score -5):

I can recommend you a youtube channel :Coaching, it focuses on jee main and meet but it's quick revision videos and detailed solutions of jee main questions of previous year with learning of concepts in maths and physics are a good resource for any aspirant for jee main or advanced. I am an aspirant myself and I would too give the exam next year and I use primarily the material given by my coaching institute, concepts of physics by HC Verma it is one of the best book for concepts, one must do the objective and short answer questions thoroughly as every year atleast one question appears directly or indirectly from this book. I also recommend using Physics books (2 volumes) on mechanics by Er. Anurag Mishra it's one of the best book for variety of problems, different patterns of questions and the level of problems is tougher than actual jee advanced test. You can also solve IE Irodov for further practice but keep in mind that the jee level will never touch the level of both the books, but if do them well, they will help you strengthen the application of concepts that you learned.  All the best.

Comment: The use of [run-on sentences](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/GRAMMAR/runons.htm), and the absence of any paragraph breaks, make this answer very hard to understand.